# Linux porting for RISCV multicore processor

Tags: linux, multicore, bootloader, toolchain, riscv

We are developing a multi-core processor with RISCV architecture.

We had already ported Linux for single-core RISCV processor and it is working on our own FPGA based board with busybox rootfs.

I want to port Linux for multi-core RISCV processor now.

My doubts are:

1. Whether the  gnu-riscv-gcc toolchain available now supports multi-core?
2. Whether spike available now supports multi-core?
3. Should I make any change to the bbl bootloader (Berkely bootloader) to support multi-core?
4. What are the changes I should make for my single-core Linux kernel to support multi-core?

Answer (score 2):

The current RISC-V ecosystem already supports SMP Linux.

1. No changes to the compiler are required for multicore.
2. Spike can simulate multicore when using the '-p' flag.
3. BBL supports multicore.
4. Before building linux, configure it to support SMP.

Any hiccups, are probably due to the toolchain out of sync with the newest privileged spec changes. Last Fall, users successfully built and ran multicore Linux on RISC-V.

Comment: This sounds great, could you provide names of the projects of those who have succeeded in running Linux on multi-core RISC-V designs?  That way we can search on the projects and go read about their experiences, if they have posted anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is all expected to work out of the box.  My standard testing flow for Linux and QEMU pull requests is to boot a Fedora root filesystem on QEMU via Linux+BBL.  Instructions can be found on the [QEMU Wiki Article about RISC-V](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/RISCV).  This will boot in our "virt" board, which uses VirtIO based devices.  These devices have standard upstream Linux drivers that are very well supported, so there isn't really any platform-level work to be done.

In addition to the standard VirtIO-based devices, SiFive has devices that are part of the Freedom SOC platform.  If you platform differs significantly from SiFive's Freedom platform then you'll need some additional drivers in both Linux and BBL. 
 We maintain an out-of-tree version of the drivers we haven't cleaned up for upstream yet in [freedom-u-sdk](https://github.com/sifive/freedom-u-sdk), which should give you a rough idea of how much work it is.  Running `make qemu` in that repository will boot Linux on QEMU via BBL, and running `make` will show you how to flash an SD card image for the HiFive Unleashed board.